# How to handle different ruby version requirements between chef 10.28.0 and ohai 8.0.1

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, ohai-gem

I'm trying to build a server on rackspace using chef 10.28.0, building the exact same configuration that I've built three times before without any changes. The only difference is that chef installed ohai 7.4.0 on the previous runs and this time it is installing ohai 8.0.1.

The problem is that chef 10.28.0 installs ruby 1.9.3, whereas ohai 8.0.1 requires ruby 2.0.0 or greater. From my googling I have found that chef 10 supports ruby 2.0 but installs ruby 1.9 by default. Is there any way to get chef 10 to install ruby 2.0 instead? Barring that, is there any way to get chef 10 to install ohai 7.4 instead of 8.0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Do you just want a running Chef installation? Chef 10 is really old also.. Probably just do what *coderanger* says :)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the omnibus installer packages. These include Ruby, Chef, Ohai, and all the other dependencies in a working configuration. You can download older versions of the omnibus installers from [the download page](https://www.chef.io/download-chef-client/):

[image]

Or you can use the `-v` option to the bootstrap scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the bootstrap scripts. We are using custom bootstrap scripts and the versions for ruby, chef and ohai are all in there.